# Updating id of models without deleting objects in it in Django

Tags: django

I am studiying the bases of django by watching courses of "Tech with Tim" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1mokevMWk&t=2912s
I deleted objects in models and my id always incremented instead of making reset.
How can I reset my id?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nkm6.png)

```
from typing import Text
from django.db import models


class ToDoList (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Please *don't*. This has been asked numerous times, and this is not a good idea: it means that people who bookmarked the old item, now all of a sudden are referred to a new item/todo list...

Answer (score 0):

Never reset `id` in database. It is way safer to keep "empty slot" than reusing such id for many reasons.